# How to include jmods with R8 in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-r8, rt.jar

With older JDK versions I included `rt.jar` in R8 configuration with

```
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
```

In order to meet requirements of various java libraries not Android-specific (NOTE this doesn't mean that whole `rt.jar` will be included in App, it's just a practical way to avoid R8 optimization to strip away important Java SE code without configuring all keep whitelist one by one)

With JDK above 8 `rt.jar` is no longer available and it has been replaced by `jmods`, searching seems the proguart syntax to include equivalent jmods alternative to `rt.jar` seems to be

```
-libraryjars  <java.home>/jmods/java.base.jmod(!**.jar,!module-info.class)
```

So I have tried it, but unfortunately with R8 I get this error:

```
Unexpected input type. Only archive types are supported, e.g., .jar, .zip, etc.
```

What is the correct way to include it?

Comment: What Java `rt.jar` good for inside APK/AAR? I find that highly questionable.

Comment: @MartinZeitler It doesn't include rt.jar in App released, but it avoid optimization to strip away some Java SE libraries without the need to configure all special exception one by one.

Comment: Well, the Java SE SDK `rt.jar` has absolutely nothing to do with Android SDK `android.jar`. This does not belong into the package, because the target device has the runtime anyway. Don't mix Standard Edition (desktop) with Android Java (mobile). This means, even if you somehow manage to stuff it into the package, it's just bloat which might even be optimized (not packaged, because it's not being used).

Comment: @MartinZeitler Of course it is not part of Android SDK (the point to include it is exactly this),  but you are failing to understand the reason why I do this.  I guess you have used thirdy party jars not part of Android SDK!?! That is what I'm doing, the only difference is that these are also part of Java Se and I avoid a lot of time wasted in keep this keep that in obfuscator config with just a code line, including rt.jar is nothing more than a whitelist trick for shrinker/obfuscator in this case.

Comment: Consider the whole resulting apk is just 7MB (and it doesn't include any native code that may cause compatibility issues). I have used this method for long time, the problem is only with R8 shrinker now that I have migrated my code to Java 11 due to jmods.

Comment: The target device has `rt.jar` and `android.jar`... and this `rt.jar` will not be processed anyway. And you don't even have to use R8, but ProGuard can still be applied: https://github.com/Guardsquare/proguard

Answer (score 0):

When R8 is *not* used for Android projects (where `android.jar` is the runtime library) one needs the Java runtime library, which was in `rt.jar` until Java 8. For later JDKs a file system provider is included in `$JAVA_HOME/lib/jrt-fs.jar`. R8 has support for using that by passing the `JAVA_HOME` directory as the library path to R8, so:

```
  $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp r8-jar com.android.tools.r8.R8 --lib $JAVA_HOME ...
```

Will work for all JDK versions. If the `JAVA_HOME` has a `rt.jar` that is used and otherwise the file system provider is used to find the runtime library. See the code for handling this [here](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/d940a4dfc8149f4f65dba5dce6b27bd5fa5e8e8c/src/main/java/com/android/tools/r8/BaseCompilerCommandParser.java#284).

Note, this does not work when using `-libraryjars` in a configuration file, only for the `--lib` argument directly to R8. Opened [issue 260213385](https://issuetracker.google.com/260213385) on that.

Also note that, that when the file system provider is loaded it will always expose the runtime of the *running* JVM, so doing this

```
  $JAVA_HOME_1/bin/java -cp r8-jar com.android.tools.r8.R8 --lib $JAVA_HOME_2 ...
```

you will still see the the runtime of `JAVA_HOME_1` if `JAVA_HOME_2` is for JDK-9 or newer.